# How do I connect to a MySQL database from another computer in VB.NET?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql, vb.net

How do I connect to a database of another computer in the same local network using VB.NET? We have already enabled remote connection in the SQL Server configuration and the SQL browser, and we already connected with one another using wireless network. Here is our connection in VB.NET:

`Data Source=NEWUSER0602akz\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=sample;Integrated Security=True`

Is there something wrong with this? When I input data, it always shows me the error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing to SQL Server

Why it is always showing this, even though we already set the remote connection?

Comment: Did you specify the port?

Comment: This question has been edited twice but no one has questioned the confusion over "MySQL" in the title and SQL Server in the body.  Is it possible that the poster meant "my SQL" - i.e. "the SQL server that is mine" and not MySQL?  The grammar in the original unedited question implies English as a second language.

Answer (score 0):

You say your database is MySQL but in your connection string you are trying to connect to a server named "SQLExpress", which would certainly be a Microsoft SQL Server Express instance, not MySQL.

In Visual Studio (or Visual Studio Express), use the Server Explorer, right click on "Data Connections", and select "Add Connection"  Then click "Change" on the Data Source field - as shown here:

[image]

You then select your data provider:

[image]

As shown, MySQL is not one of the supported database programs in a standard installation of Visual Studio.  However, there are plenty of (Free) choices for a .NET/MySql data provider - Google for "mysql .net data provider".  Install one, follow the steps above, and you should be all set.